# Does Java optimize new HashSet(someHashSet).contains() to be O(1)?

Tags: performance, complexity-theory, java

This class is an example of where the issue arises:

```
public class ContainsSet {
    private static HashSet<E> myHashSet;

    [...]

    public static Set<E> getMyHashSet() {
        return new HashSet<E>(myHashSet);
    }

    public static boolean doesMyHashSetContain(E e) {
        return myHashSet.contains(e);
    }
}
```

Now imagine two possible functions:

```
boolean method1() {
    return ContainsSet.getMyHashSet().contains(someE);
}
boolean method2() {
    return ContainsSet.doesMyHashSetContain(someE);
}
```

Now is my question whether or not method 1 will have the same time complexity after Java optimization as method 2.
(I used `HashSet` instead of just `Set` to emphasize that `myHashSet.contains(someE)` has complexity `O(1)`.)

Without optimization it would not. Although `.contains()` has complexity `O(1)`, the `new HashSet<E>(myHashSet)` has complexity `O(n)`, which would give method 1 a complexity of `O(n) + O(1) = O(n)`, which is horrible compared to the beloved `O(1)`.

The reason why I this issue is imported is because I am teached not to return lists or sets if you will not allow an external class to change the contents of it. Returning a copy is an obvious solution, but it can be really time-consuming.

Comment: `new HashSet(anotherHashSet).contains()` == `anotherHashSet.contains()`

Comment: Set is just an interface, the class implementing it is (in your case) HashSet so there's no difference

Comment: Sure? Besides, you call the `.contains()` on a return value of a method. So they are in different files. So at compile time, your equation does not hold.
Are you sure it will always be so?

Comment: Use an immutable `Set` (such as Guava's [`ImmutableSet`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet.html)) and you won't have to return a copy at all.

Comment: @GuilhermeTorresCastro True, but I tend to be as general as possible with variable declarations and return types. Normally I will always type `Set<E> mySet = new HashSet<E>()`, but I always used HashSet here to be specific.

Comment: @FrankPavageau Of course, I do want it to be mutable from within it's own class.

Comment: @StevenRoose You can still create a new, modified instance of the `Set`  to replace the previous one, it's not incompatible. Of course, the cost depends on the ratio of reads and writes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, `javac` does not (and cannot) optimize this away. It's required to emit the byte code you describe in your source to this level. And the JVM will not be nearly intelligent enough to optimize this away. It's way too likely to have side effects to prove.

Don't return a copy of the `HashSet` if you want immutability. Wrap it in an unmodifiable wrapper: `Collections.unmodifiableSet(myHashSet)`

Comment: I assumed it was not possible at compile time, but I thought maybe at runtime it was. At runtime you can see all instructions chronologically so it would be more obviously visible that the optimization is possible.

Comment: I don't necessarily want immutability, I only want the set from my class to be immutable. But if the caller wants to play with the set, I'd want him to be free to do so. But for this purpose I will probably use your solution and document the fact that it's an immutable set.

Comment: @StevenRoose But the instructions will be doing something (comparing hashCodes, creating `Map.Entry`s, etc.) and could not be eliminated.

Comment: If you clearly specify that your method returns an immutable collection, the caller knows exactly what he can and cannot do. If he needs to modify the collection for his own purposes, he can just as easily take a copy (and will be greeted by an `UnsupportedOperationException` if he fails to do so). This seems reasonable to me in the common scenario where reads are more frequent than writes.

Comment: If the caller wants a mutable copy it can always call `new HashSet()` itself.

Answer (score 0):

What can I say here but that creating a new HashSet and populating it via the constructor is expensive!

Java will not "optimize away" this work: Even though you and I know it would give the same result as "passing through" the contains() call, java can not know this.

Answer (score 0):

No. That is beyond optimization. You returned a new object and you could use it in somewhere else, Java is not supposed to omit it. A new HashSet will be created.

This is not a good practice to return a copy. It's not only time consuming but also space consuming. As Sean said, you can wrap with unmodifiableSet or you can wrap it in your own class.

You can try this:

```
public static Set<E> getMyHashSet() {
    return Collection.unmodifiableSortedSet(myHashSet);
}
```

Note: use that method will return a view of your set, not a copy.